# Questions regarding the fundamental theorem of galois theory

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

From what I have read, the fundamental theorem of Galois theory states that there is a bijection between subfields of a splitting field of a polynomial and subgroups of the Galois group.

One question I have is that why do the automorphisms in the Galois group have to fix the polynomial of the splitting field?

In the case where $B = A(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the root to the minimal polynomial f(x), and the Galois group is $Aut(B/A)$, Is it because transforming the polynomial means A isn't fixed?

Another way to ask this is that do all possible automorphisms of $B$ that fixes $A$ also fixes $f(x)$? If not, then why are those automorphisms not in the galois group?

Comment: $f$ needs to be a polynomial in $A[x]$. Because its coefficients are in $A$, they are fixed by any element of $\mathrm{Aut}(B/A)$.

Comment: "why do the automorphisms in the Galois group have to fix the polynomial of the splitting field?" that's by definition of Galois group. This is like asking "why do even numbers have to be divisible by 2?"